# If_else statement i wrote does not solve my dataframe manipulation below

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to move the time elements of `df$V1` to `df$V2`, so that all the time values are held in one column (`df$V2`), and only date elements remain in `df$V1`.

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c("12:12:00", "", "01/09/2009", "04/09/2009"),
                 V2=c("", "02:24:00", "08:45:00", "15:30:00"))
```

Here is my unsuccessful attempt with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
mutate(V1 = if_else(V1 == " ", V2, V1)) %>%
mutate(V2 = if_else(V1 == V2, " ", V2))
```

Comment: Please add language tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `base` R solution. The first line copies the 'time' elements of V1 to V2, while preserving the V1 'date' elements. The second line replaces the 'time' values in V1 with an empty character. This solution assumes that the ':' symbol is unique to the in 'time' elements, and not found in the 'date' elements.

```
# copy elements of V1 to V2 if they contain a colon
df$V2 <- ifelse(grepl(":", df$V1), df$V1, df$V2)

# repalce ':' containing elements of V1 with ""
df$V1 <- ifelse(grepl(":", df$V1), "", df$V1)

> df
V1       V2
1            12:12:00
2            02:24:00
3 01/09/2009 08:45:00
4 04/09/2009 15:30:00
```